# linux built-in read command flags

Tags: linux, shell, bamboo, built-in

I am running into an odd situation. I am on RHEL 6.3.  I am trying to use the built-in 'read' command to read the lines in the file in an array and to process it.

In my script, I am using

```
while IFS=" " read -r -a appInfo
do
    echo "4 ${appInfo[0]}"
    echo "4 ${appInfo[1]}"
    echo "4 ${appInfo[2]}"
    echo "4 line *{appInfo[@]}"
    currentApp="${appInfo[*]}"
.....
done < details.txt
```

It is working fine, when I execute the script from the command line.  The read command shows the below info

```
read: usage: read [-ers] [-a array] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]
```

If I do `read --version` on command line, I get

**Commandline** version         read (AT&T Research) 2006-12-19

But when I try to execute the exact same script from a Bamboo project,  the read command generates an error

```
read: -a: unknown option
Usage: read [-ACprsv] [-d delim] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-n nchar] [-N nchar]
            [var?prompt] [var ...]
```

**Bamboo :** version         read (AT&T Research) 2006-12-19

So, if the version shows the same, why do the flags show differently?

What could be the problem.  How can I solve the issue, so that I can read the line into an array even when running it from a Bamboo plan?

Comment: RHEL 6.3 has reached [end-of-life](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata).  As current systems tend to have fewer bugs than older systems, is there a good reason not to upgrade?

Comment: Not sure.  That decision is made by our operations teams, we generally don't have any weight in those. :(  In this case, though, why is there a difference in behaviour?

Comment: I don't use RHEL/bamboo but, judging by the `read` help message, it looks to me like your command line script is running under `bash` while the bamboo script is running `ksh`.

Comment: Thanks.  I will check on that.  Both are running under default shell.  So, from your comment, I gather that the default shell on the server is set to bash shell when I log-in with my id, where as the account running Bamboo plan may have been set as ksh.  I need to read more about how the default shell is set-up and find out how they are set-up in both these situations.

Comment: @John1024 - Thanks for the suggestion.  That was the issue.  I replaced the #!/bin/sh   with    #!/bin/bash   and  was able to proceed,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @John1024, I was able to fix the problem by changing the #! line to #!/bin/bash from #!/bin/sh ( which was running the default ksh shell ).

The credit of solution goes to @John1024, just putting this as an answer so that it can be marked as a solution to question.